# d3.simplify.js simplify without projecting

Tags: d3.js, simplification

Is there any way to simplify a features collection in SRID 4326 and maintain the same coordinate reference. Seems like most example project to a pixel based coordinate system.

Comment: See this thread from d3js Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/NjBWg5NZOfk